Hide Dashboard action buttons in Experience Cloud
Is there any way that we can hide Dashboard action buttons in Experience Cloud?
I tried using override CSS feature by getting the class name through elements but it doesn't seem to work.
Is there any workaround for it?


Hiding dashboard action buttons directly in Experience Cloud isn't possible through standard configuration.
However, you can achieve a similar outcome using a Visualforce page that embeds the dashboard without the action buttons.
You can refer this page for more details
Thanks
